# How to get rails to return SUM(columnName) attributes with right datatype instead of a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Assume a query of the following form

```
operatingExpenses = Expense.find(:all,
      {:select=>"categories.activityType, categories.name heading, sum(amount) totalAmount",
      :joins => "inner join expense_categories categories on category_id = categories.id ",
      :group => "categories.activityType, categories.name",
      :order => "categories.activityType, totalAmount DESC"}
      )
```

Now amount is defined as a decimal field in the database schema. e.g. definition in the Rails Migration would be

```
create_table :expenses do |table|
  table.column :created_at, :timestamp, :null=>false
  table.column :description, :string, :limit=>100, :null=>false
  table.column :amount, :decimal, :scale=>2, :precision=>10, :null=>false
  table.column :category_id, :integer, {:null=>false, :default =>1} 
end
```

Now the set of records returned by the query fails the following assert

```
assert_equal 800, operatingExpenses[1].totalAmount

<800> expected but was <"800.00">.
```

Why is the Sum/aggregate column returned as a string instead of the same datatype as the summed up database column? I'd like to avoid sprinkling `.to_s` or `.to_f` everywhere to get around this. Any ideas ?

What I'm trying to get at the end of this rainbow is a cashflow listing like this - (for a specified daterange.. an additional condition to the query listed above).

```
   cat Type      Heading      TotalAmount 
|  Operating |  ExpCatX001  | 4000 |
|            |  ExpCatX002  |  200 |
|  Financing |  ExpCatX003  | 1000 |
|  Investing |  ExpCatX004  | 4234 |
|            |  ExpCatX005  |  201 |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For custom queries that require basically a whole custom SQL statement (your find above doesn't exactly abstract much from you) I like to set up a quick little new model that represents the new information.  i.e.

```
class OperatingExpenseReportDatum
  attr_accessor :type, :heading, :total

  def initialize(row)
    # set values from row, like
    @total = row["total"].to_f
  end
end
```

and then write a helper method into the model, something like:

```
class Expense < AR::Base
  ...
  def self.operating_expenses
    rows = connection.select_all "SQL STATEMENT HERE"
    rows.map { |row| OperatingExpenseReportDatum.new(row) }
  end
end
```

Then your report generation is all nice:

```
#controller
@expenses = Expense.operating_expenses

#view
<% @expenses.each do |expense| %>
  <%= expense.type %>: <%= expense.total %>
<% end %>
```

Or something similar.  :)

Comment: Thanks.. the most 'natural' solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Active record is trying to return "Expense" objects built from the results of your query.  But expense objects don't have a totalAmount field, so this is unrequested "bonus data" as far as ActiveRecord can tell.  It coud just throw it out, but instead it keeps it for you, with the most forgiving type assumptions it can.

My suggestions:

- Don't do this; it isn't the way Active record is supposed to work; the total of the details belongs to whatever is rolling them up; it isn't a detail object itself.
- If you must treat it as a detail, name the field `amount` so ActiveRecord knows what to do with it.
- If you must have the total as its own field, add an accessor in your Expense model like so:

  ```
  def total_amount
      totalAmount.to_f
      end
  ```

  and use it like so: `operatingExpenses[1].total_amount` in your code.

Comment: The category.name as heading bit is similar - it adds a non-existant field (which is actually just an association pass-through) to the expense model. From what I can tell of the SQL, it's not even necessary, as all the Expense objects returned will be in the same category.

Comment: (...continued) So I would take that out too and just use the Category object directly with the list of Expense objects.

Comment: @Sarah - all expenses do not belong to the same category - the SQL returns all entered expenses grouped by the associated category activityType first and then by name.

Comment: bullet#1 looks like you mean a new plain ruby class  which does the computation in code and exposes typed attributes - which uses AR to read expense (amount), expense.category (name, activityType) ?  didnt realize i may be on the wrong path ; AR makes it so easy to do it the DB Way.

Comment: @Gishu -- Maybe.  Or have an ActiveRecord model (called rollup or something) that you populate from your query.  Or have the summing be a function of the Category (not the expenses).  There are lots of ways to do it.  But when you call Expense.find() AR expects to get data to populate an Expense.

Comment: Opt#1 it is too much work to duplicate SQL Grouping, Summing & Sorting Opt#2 Hides Intent.. just to make AR work Opt#3 - chosen by process of elimination. actually a variation of Opt#3 as seen in the acc answer.

Comment: @Gishu -- Fighting your tools is never wise in the long run.  That table "belongs to" Active Record and you make your code needlessly brittle by messing with it directly.  How would you react to a C programmer who insisted on opening SQL databases as files and messing with the bytes directly?

Answer (score 1):

Because with `:select` Rails gives you no way of telling it (or the driver) to what kind of native type to bind the result set's fields (once it's all retrieved -- although most of not all drivers *will* know, internally, what the column SQL types are) -- so it's all recorded as strings and the SQL type information is generally thrown away.  This applies to all fields all the time.  You have to perform the conversion manually (`to_f`), just like Rails' `ActiveRecord.instantiate` method has to, internally, when you use plain `ActiveRecord.find` without `:select` or `:joins` (and it has to populate a non-string attribute.)

You may confirm this by looking at your database driver's `select_raw` method.

Cheers,
V.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `find_by_sql` and apply the `SUM` on a decimal column :

```
operating_expenses = Expense.find_by_sql ['SELECT cat.activityType, cat.name heading, SUM(exp.amount) AS amount FROM expenses exp JOIN expense_categories cat ON exp.category_id = cat.id GROUP BY cat.id, cat.activityType, cat.name, exp.id ORDER BY cat.activityType, amount DESC']
```

Under the 'amount' column of 
operating_expenses you'll got your total automatically converted to decimal.

**N.B.** : cat.id and exp.id are required to respect SQL standard.