# How I can count the total votes in worker table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'am confused when I try to count the total votes in my votes table in rails..

```
serviceproviders has_many votes
votes belongs_to serviceproviders
```

I tried like this :

```
sp = Serviceprovider.joins(:votes).group_by(&:id).count
```

but it doesn't get the right output.

example output I want is:

If in the table Jhon Doe has 5 row of votes in the table, I can get the total 5 votes when I query. Can any give me the idea how can execute the query. Thank you!

Update:

Thank you for those answers.

I tried this in my rails c.

```
vote = Vote.joins(:serviceprovider).group(:serviceprovider_id).count
```

and I got the results: `{108=>2, 109=>1}`

My question how can I get the top 10 highest votes?

Comment: If you want to count how many votes for "John Doe" then somewhere in your command for `sp = Serviceprovider...` you're going to need to mention `'John Doe'` but you don't.

Comment: Can you provide some more info about your schema, and exactly what you want?  What is "Jhon Doe" here - is he a ServiceProvider?  If so then you will probably want to say something like `@service_provider = ServiceProvider.find_by_id(params[:id]); @vote_count = @service_provider.votes.count`

Comment: Thank you sir. What if I want to count each votes in serviceprovider and get the top 10 highest votes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the table:

```
app_development=# select * from votes;

 id |  city   |         created_at         |         updated_at         | service_provider_id
----+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------
  1 | B\'lore  | 2015-02-19 17:35:58.061324 | 2015-02-19 17:35:58.083479 |                   3
  2 | Kol     | 2015-02-19 17:35:58.103013 | 2015-02-19 17:35:58.123405 |                   2
  3 | Mum     | 2015-02-19 17:35:58.11242  | 2015-02-19 17:35:58.125345 |                   2
  4 | Kochin  | 2015-02-19 17:35:58.136139 | 2015-02-19 17:35:58.167971 |                   1
  5 | Mum     | 2015-02-19 17:35:58.145833 | 2015-02-19 17:35:58.170319 |                   1
  6 | Chennai | 2015-02-19 17:35:58.156755 | 2015-02-19 17:35:58.171996 |                   1
(6 rows)

app_development=# select * from service_providers;

 id | name |         created_at         |         updated_at
----+------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | MTS  | 2015-02-19 17:35:57.837508 | 2015-02-19 17:35:57.837508
  2 | HCL  | 2015-02-19 17:35:57.923479 | 2015-02-19 17:35:57.923479
  3 | ACL  | 2015-02-19 17:35:57.934414 | 2015-02-19 17:35:57.934414
```

You need the following query to obtain the desired result :

```
Vote.joins(:service_provider)
    .group(:service_provider_id)
    .order("count_all desc")
    .limit(10)
    .count
```

Tested in Rails *console* :

```
[arup@app]$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.1)
[1] pry(main)> Vote.joins(:service_provider).group(:service_provider_id).order("count_all desc").limit(2).count
   (2.0ms)  SELECT  COUNT(*) AS count_all, service_provider_id AS service_provider_id FROM "votes" INNER JOIN "service_providers" ON "service_providers"."id" = "votes"."service_provider_id" GROUP BY service_provider_id  ORDER BY count_all desc LIMIT 2
=> {1=>3, 2=>2}
[2] pry(main)>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir but I got an error SyntaxError: (irb):47: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting ')'
...("count(serviceprovider_id)" AS vote_count).order("vote_coun...

Comment: @JuanDelaCruz Try now.. I'm your friend.. not Sir :-)

Comment: Sorry my friend .. :) I got an error again ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(count(serviceprovider_id) AS vote_count) AS cou... 
 It seems like "AS" has a problem. I'm using rails 4.1 is it valid?

Comment: @JuanDelaCruz there might be silly mistakes.. I'm working on it.. Just give some moments..

Comment: @JuanDelaCruz Updated,,, Now it will work..

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it. I also created my own solution using SELECT but yours is much better. :)

Comment: Just ask a separate question..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sp = ServiceProvider.find_by_name("Jhon Doe");  
@votes = sp.votes.count
```