# Rails 2.2.2: find_by_sql returns result set with all columns value as object of String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, find-by-sql

I have used find_by_sql to get UNION of two tables which has some extra columns than Model which have used to call find_by_sql,

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

```
class Shape < ActiveRecord::Base
   # columns
   # shape_id -> Integer
end

class Circle < ActiveRecord::Base
   # columns
   # circle_id -> Integer
   # created_at -> Datetime 
   # update_at -> Datetime 
end

class Square < ActiveRecord::Base
   # columns
   # square_id -> Integer
   # created_at -> Datetime 
   # update_at -> Datetime 
end
```

I have taken UNION of circles & squares using Shape model like follows:

```
@shapes = Shape.find_by_sql("select circle_id as id, created_at, updated_at from circles UNION select square_id as id, created_at, updated_at from squares")
```

Now, when I use @shapes to display all records with created_at and updated_at it always returned in string object like follows:

```
for shape in @shapes
  puts shape['id'].class.inspect # String
  puts shape['created_at'].class.inspect # String
  puts shape['updated_at'].class.inspect # String
end
```

Now, what is best way using which I can get that all values as object of type defined in database like follows:

```
for shape in @shapes
  puts shape['id'].class.inspect # Integer
  puts shape['created_at'].class.inspect # DateTime
  puts shape['updated_at'].class.inspect # DateTime
end
```

Comment: Take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659523/how-to-get-rails-to-return-sumcolumnname-attributes-with-right-datatype-instea

Comment: @Vik - thanks! I have looked around it & I have already decided to go with that solution but I want to make sure whether it is only a way to achieve this because I have lots of fields with different datatypes like integer, datetime, decimal, date...

Comment: In 2.3 it returns Time object, as expected..

Comment: @Mik_Die for me its not returns related object even in 2.3

Comment: I checked it in 2.3.8, and you?

Comment: Are you using the mysql or mysql2 gem?

Comment: @FrederickCheung - it is pgsql